# STM32 Using SWCLK and USART on the same PCB

Tags: stm32, uart

I designed a custom PCB which uses STM32F030C8 chip. I was wondering if it's possible to use debugging capabilities as well as UART communication on the same pin (PA14). It's not possible to attach two different functions on the same pin in CubeMx but i made some checks using difftool and nothing seems to change for SWCLK configuration. Also as far as i know, there should be some pull-ups on UART pins so will it also affect debugging?

Comment: As the chip comes out of reset, the pin will be configured as SWD.  Reconfiguration of the pin with the UART alternate function requires user code writing to memory-mapped pin configuration registers.  After that, SWD will stop working until the next reset / power cycle.  But you can put the pin configuration code in a conditional (`if`) and skip switching the pin to UART some of the time.  This won't help you debug the UART code, of course.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't really need debugging and uart at the same time as uart won't be active in the final code. What about pull-ups required by the UART? Do i need to use external resistors on the host or i can leave a resistor on pcb for both functions?

Comment: It's SWD, not UART, that needs pullups, and the programmable pullups inside the chip should be strong enough and automatically enabled appropriately for SWD as the chip comes out of reset.

Comment: All that said, I was once given a board designed like that, and having the user code turn off SWD for other purposes made not just debugging but also loading new code one of the biggest headaches imaginable.  I definitely recommend leaving the SWD pins dedicated in all future designs.

Comment: I skimmed again found these on the datasheet. 1) "After reset, these pins are configured as SWDIO and SWCLK alternate functions, and the internal pull-up on
SWDIO pin and internal pull-down on SWCLK pin are activated" 2) For UART "A pull-up resistor must be added, if pull-up resistor are not connected in host side".

Comment: I'm thinking flashing between two versions of the code for each functionality.

Comment: Maybe those are open-drain pins that can't drive high?  You can't put an external pullup on SWCLK because it will interfere with SWD.  But UART should work if you enable the internal pullup (for SWD pullup SWDIO and pulldown SWCLK which is the default, for UART pullup both)

Comment: Can you provide a source of that quote about pull-up on UART? It is highly unusual, even if you use UART in single-wire half-duplex mode

Comment: @Maple It's on AN2606 datasheet page 37.

Comment: Do you **have** a RS232 transceiver chip on your PCB? And if you do then does it ever have high impedance state enabled? That schematic in AN2606 is rather problematic, as it depends on many implementation-specific factors and use cases

Comment: I will use USB-TTL converter module(CP2102) on the PC side. I don't have any related chip on PCB.

Comment: then you don't need any pull-ups on PCB, but you do need to understand what happens when you plug either SWD or UART adapter and keep in mind the boot sequence of the device. You may need series resistor on SWCLK line, since it is also used as TX from STM

Comment: As @BenVoigt said in the very first comment, your best bet is to delay UART initialization to allow SWD connection. However this only applicable for "normal" UART use. If you also want to use UART bootloader (as the reference to AN2606 implies) then you are positioning yourself for a huge pain in the posterior, as you also have been told. Choose one method of programming and stick with it. Or better yet, use different UART port

Comment: I will only be using UART on my so called "calibration" mode so it won't be even used in the final code which is why i didn't want to complicate things(which i guess made it more complicated). I also won't be needing UART and SWD simultaneously. I believe i can get around with my current design now.

Comment: If you can leave the pins in SWD mode unless a "start calibration" command is received that also enables the UART, then things should not get too ugly.

Comment: That is a doable scenario. Thanks for all answers