# How to detect if STM32 is in debug mode? (to select between UART and SWCLK pin)

Tags: stm32, uart

We have a project with STM32F051 and now we need to use UART2 and the only unused pins are the pins 37 (SWCLK) and 38. I know there is another post with this topic.
[STM32 Using SWCLK and USART on the same PCB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/592437/stm32-using-swclk-and-usart-on-the-same-pcb).

In this post Ben Voigt wrote

> But you can put the pin configuration code in a conditional (if) and skip switching the pin to UART some of the time.

Now my question:

**Is there any possibility to know if the device is in DEBUG mode?**

I'd use this as condition to configure the UART or not. For me it's not needed to have this UART pin during debugging, it's only used in normal operation.

Comment: Have you checked the reference manual on that?

Comment: if you have a debug and release build of the code, have it so the debug build does not enable the uart.

Answer (score 0):

Those detection methods won't be reliable IMHO. There is quite a bit of debug registers that are not accessible from the MCU inside.

I recommend to wait a significant amount of time - at least 5-10 seconds - before switching the debug pin functions.

That allows a debugger to reliably connect to the chip after reset. Then you can set a variable in the debugger that tells your code to not switch pin functions.

Comment: Thanks. Please can you give me an example how to do this: "Then you can set a variable in the debugger"

Comment: *"I recommend to wait a significant amount of time - at least 5-10 seconds"* It is a obvious nonsense. Debug mode is active from instruction the first instruction. If you want to make sure - simply connect under reset